# req.body only works on form? node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, ejs

How do I use req.body from a body-parser library

How do I get a value of p , button or any other html tags other than input?

test.ejs:

```
<button name="button">1</button>
<p name="p">This value needs to be changed</p>
```

routes.js:

```
// Assume that body-parser has been configured
router.post('/testRoute', function(req, res) {
   button = req.body.button;
   pTag = req.body.p;

   /// Its not working :(

})
```

How do I get the value of button or p Tag? I need to do some data manipulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See,

`req.body` is not same as `body` of the html. Only form elements can be serialized to send the data back to server or if you are using ajax from the client then you can target the specific element to send it back to server.

using ajax *(as jQuery is tagged)* use `submit` event :

```
$('#formID').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // <----stops the form to get submitted
   $.ajax({
      url:'/testRoute',
      data:{
             button:$('button[name="button"]').attr('name'), // <---send button name
             p     :$('p[name="p"]').text() // send the p's text.
      },
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data); // logs the response from the server.
      },
      error:function(){}
  });
});
```

and this just doesn't make any sense to have a `name` attribute on `<p>` elements instead you can add a class name:

```
<p class="p">This value needs to be changed</p>
```

then in the data you can change to class selector:

```
    data:{
           button:$('button[name="button"]').attr('name'), // <---send button name
           p     :$('.p').text() // send the p's text.
    },
```

Comment: Theres no other way to get the value of the targeted tags?

Comment: @JackMoscovi you can use JS/AJAX for that as it was suggested by Jai

Comment: We can send complete form using serialize method
 data:  $( "form" ).serialize()

Comment: @Dineshaws but you can't send a `<p>` tag text with it...;), you have to explicitly set it to send.